# How can I get the file path of a file saved by the user in my program in Java?

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

I am creating a program that applies a filter to an image and afterwards gives the user the option of darkening the image or making it lighter. Before the image is filtered the user picks a save location for the new image. Is there anyway I can get the filepath of that location they choose to save it to? I am using `JFileChooser` to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`JFileChooser#getSelectedFile`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#getSelectedFile()) returns a `java.io.File` of the selected file (or `null` if they didn't pick something).

Have a look at [How to Use File Choosers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html) for more details

You could use [`File#getParentFile`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getParentFile()) to return just the path element (without the file name) of the `File` object if all you want is the path, otherwise you have an abstract representation of the `File` which the user selected...

Answer (score 0):

If you're using JFileChooser you can use `getSelectedFile()` and `getPath()` or `getAbsolutePath()`